# cancan and namespace - how to change`current_user'" to current_profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have model profile instead of user and when I`m trying to do sth like that :

```
  <% if can? :update, @article %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %> |
  <% end %>
```

I got en error: 
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #

I am also using namespace Admin, so I have http://localhost:3000/admin/profile and so on. 
Can you please tell me how to change defaults settings ? I have tried to put:

```
  def current_ability
    @current_user ||= Ability.new(current_profile)
  end
```

in application_controller.rb, but still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Changing-Defaults I think it should be:

```
# in ApplicationController
def current_ability
  @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_profile)
end
```

It needs to be called **@current_ability**.